# AngularJs - Unable pass object generated by ng-repeat using ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angular-services, ng-style

I'm new to Angular, and trying to pass some data on `ng-click` between controllers using a `factory` service, based on the data returned from the server and generated by `ng-repeat` in the front.

This is the HTML:

```
<div ng-click="go('{{img.hashtag}}')" ng-repeat="img in obj" ng-style="{'background':url({{img.url}})'}">
  <span class="boxName">{{img.hashtag}}</span>
</div>
```

This works fine:

```
ng-click="selectHash($event);go('some simple string')"
```

Whereas this does not:

```
ng-click="selectHash($event);go('{{img.hashtag}}')"
```

Since its interpreted as a simple string, and not data extracted from an object.

`go` function is responsible for navigating to another page and passing the data to the corresponding `controller`:

```
$scope.go = function (hash1) {
    $location.path("hash");
    $scope.hashFac = hashFac;
    $scope.hashFac.hash = hash1;
};
```

The factory service:

```
appName.factory("hashFac",function(){
    return {

    };
});
```

How do I extract the data from the `img` object and send it onwards using `ng-click`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be really using `{{}}` interpolation directive in `ng-click` & `ng-style` directive, also while generating background url  you should use string concatenation.

```
<div ng-click="go(img.hashtag)" ng-repeat="img in obj" 
  ng-style="{'background': 'url(' + img.url + ')'}">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now the click works as needed. I tried removing the curly braces from `img.url` but I get an error `GET http://localhost/project/img.url 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried without quotes `'` and curly braces `{{}}`:

```
ng-click="selectHash($event);go(img.hashtag)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Directive `ng-click` is evaluated by Angular so you don't need to use any braces there. Merge both function calls into one:

```
$scope.buttonClicked = function(e, img) {
    // e.preventDefault() or whatever
    $scope.selectHash(e);
    $scope.go(img.hashtag);
}
```

Then in your template use just:

```
ng-click="buttonClicked($event, img)"
```